# Why does reduce fail when run inside a timer?

Tags: python

I have a script that watches for changes in another script, and re-runs the latter if it's changed. Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/91b4a820ebb862c26438c532183ded64). It's run like this:

```
~/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/blender --python script_watcher.py -- test_group.py
```

It worked ok until I used the `reduce()` function in the watched script - snippet here (`union()` is a function that creates the union of two objects):

```
def all_union(first, *others, **kwargs):
    def _(a, b):
        return union(a, b)
    r = reduce(_, others, first)
    return r
```

then I get an error message like this:

```
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

I tried replacing the timer script with one that runs only once - like this:

```
import bpy
import sys
import os
import traceback

prev = ""
curr = open(sys.argv[-1]).read()
if not prev==curr:
    print("%s changed" % sys.argv[-1])
    try:
        exec(curr)
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

and it runs perfectly - no error.

So why is `reduce()` not not working under the timer? or is the issue somewhere else?

Comment: *"Why does reduce fail when run inside a timer?"* - does reduce not fail when run outside a timer? Have you tried to use it outside a timer? Your code doesn't show that. The error message says the name is not defined, that is, Python interpreter doesn't recognize the name because it wasn't imported. You probably need `from functools import reduce`. Also this question is probably offtopic - not about Blender, but about Python.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - hi! yes, I did run the code outside the timer, that's what I tried to say at "I tried stripping everything from the timer script". Maybe it wasn't crystal clear, I tried to improve in the edit. And test_script.py does have ```from functools import reduce``` right at the top.

Comment: Did you try to reimport immediately before using it inside the timer?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - if I do ```from functools import reduce``` inside the function definiton everything works ok. Also, using ```functools.reduce()``` works ok

Comment: IMO the elephant in the room here is how you set up timer call via  `bpy.app.timers.register` . Given error message the method passed, when run from timer thread,  has no idea of the locals. As MB says simply import in the function.  Consider looking at when file was last touched, rather than constantly testing content for equality.   Recommend `pathlib` for statting  and reading text files. Also have a look at script stub template.